# How to calculate the scale of map tiles accurately?

Tags: scale

In web maps, there are two coordinate: wgs84 geographic coordinate and web mercator project coordinate. The displayed scale of a world map is the value at equator, and one 256*256 pic can contain the map in web mercator level 0.

So we can calculate the scale like this, 1:(2*pi*6378137)/(256/96*0.0254)=**1:591658710.909131**. But in the similar Esri provided service is **1:591657527.591555**[(Esri Ocean Map)](http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Ocean_Basemap/MapServer).

So, what's the affect in map display with the tiny difference? And how Esri calculate his scale?

ps: I was also confused with the same problem in wgs84.